# python converting string to int and adding 1

Tags: python

im stuck, im trying to add these together but instead of getting 8+7 = 15 im getting 8+7 = 87

I am converting count_current to an integer but it still doesn't work:

```
count_current = int(count_current)

for playlist in playlists_data:
    count_current += 1
```

any help is much appreciated
thanks
J

Comment: Your first sentence and the code do not match. In your code I cannot see 8 and I cannot see 7. Please show us the real code.

Comment: I can't see why it shouldn't work. Please post your entire code.

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't very useful.  Can you post the exception traceback (if there is one) or the actual output, with the input and expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are clearly not doing what you say you are doing:

```
>>> x = '8'
>>> y = '7'
>>> x+y
'87'
>>> x = int(x)
>>> y = int(y)
>>> x+y
15
```

Use `+` on strings and you get concatenation.  Use `+` on integers and you get addition.  If you are getting concatenation then you must be operating on strings rather than integers.